# Why are the transition probabilities for an $M/M/1$ queue $\lambda$ and $\mu$?

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process, queueing-theory

The transition state diagram for an $M/M/1$ queue is shown as [image]

The only explanation I have for the transition probabilites is that arrivals occur at rate $\lambda$ according to a Poisson process and move the process from state $i$ to $i+1$ and service completes (so departures occur) at rate $\mu$ and so this moves the process from state $i$ to $i-1$. I thought that transition diagrams show the probabilities of moving between two states so surely this explanation of how those values were obtained is not enough. How would I derive these? Or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Ib this diagram the quantities on the arrows are _rates_. There are similar diagrams where those quantities are probabilities.

Comment: Understood! Are there different names for such diagrams?

Comment: I don't know of any. You just have to tell from context.